# ExtJS setting a default sort on a remote sort store?

Tags: extjs

Is there a way in ExtJS 4.1.3 to set a default sort on a Grid with a backing store set to `remoteSort: true`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I missed the [sorters](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Sortable-cfg-sorters) config in documentation, the default sort can be set by

```
sorters: [ {
    property: 'valuetosort',
    direction: 'ASC'
} ],
```

Comment: Just as a note - this is set in store config, not in proxy config.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you want to set sorters dynamicaly and remoteSort is true, then you can use method [sort](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sort) and pass sorters configuration into single parameter.

```
store.sort([{
    property: 'valuetosort',
    direction: 'ASC'
}])
```